# Why the warning A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I filtered out the index when column value is x

Output:

```
Int64Index(\[2, 7, 8\], dtype='int64')
```

Now on these indexes I want to update value inside my df column, so I am doing

```
df['Business'][idx] = intent
```

The df gets updated but I am getting

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> df['Business'][idx] = intent

I would like to know as to why am I getting this warning?

Comment: The link provides the best explanation.

Comment: Try `df.loc[df["somecolumn"]=="x", "Bussiness"]=intent`